# How to avoid unnecessary characters in WebView

Tags: android, html, webview

I am setting String in WebView in Android, but i am getting such characters http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/5200/hkgm.jpg. How to avoid them ? IF i put a log and see then it will be proper but only in WebView it is not working properly

Thanks in advance

Code :

```
String text = "<html><body style=\"text-align:justify\"> %s </body></Html>";
String summary = rssStr.get(position).getEncodedContent();

Log.d("String", summary);
web.loadData(String.format(text, summary), "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting the Encoding type in the `Webview` can resolve this issue,

```
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, data, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: user2012 - Please see my edited question, i can't use "loadDataWithBaseURL" as i am already using "loadData"

Comment: Still then you can use the above code.Just replace "data" with "String.format(text, summary)"

Comment: user2012 - Perfect :) Worked like a charm...Thanks